# How can I prove two vertices create a parallel line along with another two points that creates 2 parallel lines in an octagon?

Tags: geometry

[image: octagon] (regular octagon)

How can I prove Line CA is parallel to DO?

I used the fact that the vertices to vertices lines are supposed to be 180 degrees, and it is a regular octagon, any line segment opposite to the original line would be parallel as it is also 180 degrees.

Also imposing coordinates on it

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I tried using the fact that the vertices to vertices lines are supposed to be 180 degrees, and it is a regular octagon, any line segment opposite to the original line would be parallel as it is also 180 degrees

Comment: @iamsogoodlo What does it mean for a line or a line segment to be $180$?

Comment: I got stuck when my teacher told me I was incorrect, and that was my only idea

Comment: @peterwhy 180 degrees*

Comment: There are so many different proofs, for example: if you know the interior angle of a regular octagon, $\angle ABC = \angle BCD = \angle CDE$ are such interior angles; $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles and you can find $\angle BCA$ and $\angle ACD$; $\angle CDO = \angle ODE = \angle CDE/2$; then two interior angles between line $CA$ and $DO$ add to $180^\circ$ means $CA\parallel DO$.

Comment: @iamsogoodlo You should [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4474963/edit) the question and add the missing part (that the octagon is a regular one), as well as your own attempts to solve the problem. Incomplete questions that show no own work are not well received around here. For a possible hint, try to see why $\,OB \perp AC\,$ and how that can help.

Comment: @peterwhy thank you!